# Google Maps API with different results between Chrome and RestTemplate

Tags: spring, google-maps, java-8, google-api, resttemplate

The service is consuming google maps api ([geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)).

When I execute a GET using default bean configuration for spring resttemplate, I have a value different from when I execute this GET on web browser (Chrome).

Call on Chrome and using resttemplate:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=mykeymykeymykeymykey&address=Rua%20Marques%20de%20Valenca,%20100,%20Alto%20da%20Mooca,%20S%C3%A3o%20Paulo%20-%20SP,%20Brasil&language=pt-BR

When I execute a reverse geocode, the chrome execution is more precise.

**Results:**
Chrome:

```
location: {
  lat: -23.5577251,
  lng: -46.5948733
},
```

RestTemplate:

```
location: {
  lat: -23.5574375,
  lng: -46.5948733
},
```

I´ve tried use Double, Float and BigDecimal. And I try create a deserializer to get this value before the serialization, but the value is the same.

I´m using Java 8 with Spring Boot 2.0.3.

Anyone knows how to accurate it?

Comment: You should open a bug for Google Map API

Comment: But is it a bug? Or maybe should I add a specific deserializer?

Comment: lng was deserialized correctly. lat is different.

Comment: @PavelMolchanov I´m working with Java deserialization. It is not because there was no error to get the value that the process of deserialization was executed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using UriComponentsBuilder and when I use toUriString the url was formatted to browser and it was not working correctly.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(googleHost)
                .queryParam("key", apiKey)
                .queryParam(input, address)
                .queryParam("language", language);
```

It´s working now using StringUtils.join(...) to build the URI.

```
String googleurl = StringUtils.join(googleGeocodingHost, 
        "?key=", apiKey, "&", input, "=", address, "&language=", language);
```